# Jersey/JaxRs wrap any response

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm looking for a way to wrap any response of my service.

I have a simple service with lots of different methods, like so

```
@Path(value = "/listSomething/{apiKey:.+}")
public List<ObjectA> listSomething(@PathParam(value = "apiKey") String apiKey)
```

Some return lists, some just some plain objects. What I want to achieve now is to wrap any of these responses surrounding them with some status information (e.g. below).

```
response {
   staus: "OK",
   data: {..the actual response..}
}
```

I tried to achieve this with some interceptor, but I had no success (**unless I add @XmlSeeAlso annotations, what I really don't want because I'd like some generic approach**). My wrapper class looks like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
//@XmlSeeAlso(ResponseA.class)
public class ResponseWrapper {

  boolean error;
  String message;
  @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
  Object object;

  public boolean isError() {
      return error;
  }

  public void setError(boolean error) {
      this.error = error;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
      return message;
  }
}
```

I tried different combinations of @XmlElement, @XmlAnyElement - without any success. I tried it inside WriterInterceptor and ContainerResponseFilter.

How can I do that simple trick (would be cool if I don't have to care if the consumer wants XML or JSON, but if I have to hack something for JSON, I'm OK with that)?

I'm feeling kind of lost at the moment. Thanks for your help.

The error I ususally get with the approaches I tried was UNKOWN_CLASS

```
   {0} nor any of its super class is known to this context.
```

My interceptor does more or less this

```
  responseContext.setGenericType(Wrapper.class);
  responseContext.setType(Wrapper.class);
  responseContext.setEntity(wrapperInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I can think of in an interceptor is:

```
Object currentEntity = responseContext.getEntity();
ResponseWrapper wrapper = new ResponseWrapper(currentEntity);
responseContext.setEntity(wrapper);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I did, but as described above it will throw an exception (unless I add the @XmlSeeAlso annotation). I know this works with CXF, I'm not sure why its not that easy with Jersey.